# how to make MyDBHelper As Global Variable?

Tags: java, android

This is my **DataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.abc2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DB_BusData";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
this.getReadableDatabase();

try {

copyDataBase();

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Error copying database");

}
}

}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void DatabaseConn(){
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
try { 
myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
} catch (IOException ioe) { 
throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
}  
try {  
myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
}catch(SQLException sqle){  
throw sqle;  
}

SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
//SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    String username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Driver_Code")).trim();
    String password = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Driver_Name")).trim();
    Log.d(null, username);
}
db.close();
}
```

Any Idea to make my myDbHelper as global variable, otherwise every function i want to call the database i need to declare it, it is inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Over `onCreate` in your `MainActivity`, and remove it from `public void DatabaseConn(){`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Singleton Database class:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourDatabaseName";

    //Declare a String for each Table name
    public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "tableName1";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "tableName2";

    //Declare a SQL string for create each table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_NAME1 ..............";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_NAME2 .................";

    private static Database Singleton = null;
    private Context context;
    private static SQLiteDatabase Db;

    private Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        this.context = context;
    }

    public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context c){
        if(Singleton == null) {
            Singleton = new Database(c.getApplicationContext());
            Db = Singleton.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return Singleton;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {

        return Db;
    }

     public synchronized void close() {

         if (Singleton != null && Db.isOpen()) Db.close();
     }


    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable  {

        try{
            close();
        }
        finally{
            super.finalize();
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //Create Tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When you need a database object:

```
SQLiteDatabase Db = Database.getInstance(context).getDatabase();
```